# Find the solution of the given initial-value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the given initial-value problem:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}+ \sqrt{1+t^2}y=0$$ with $y(0)=5$

$$y(t)=Ce^{- \int a(t)dt}$$
$$y(t)=Ce^{- \int \sqrt{1+t^2}dt}$$

I guess I kind of forgot how to solve an integral like this..

So I followed [Evaluating $\int \sqrt{1 + t^2} dt$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431143/evaluating-int-sqrt1-t2-dt)
and get this for the integral:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(t\sqrt{1+t^2}+\sinh^{-1}t\right)+C$$

$$y(t)=Ce^{- \int \sqrt{1+t^2}dt}$$
$$y(t)=Ce^{-(\frac{1}{2}\left(t\sqrt{1+t^2}+\sinh^{-1}t\right)+C)}$$
$$y(0)=Ce^{-(\frac{1}{2}\left(0\sqrt{1+0^2}+\sinh^{-1}0\right)+C)}$$
$$y(0)=Ce^{-(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sinh^{-1}0\right)+C)}=\sqrt5$$

But what is the value for $\sinh^{-1}(0)$? I can't seem to find the answer anywhere and I don't have my graphing calculator on me...I am not really familiar with hyperbolic trig functions..

Also are the C's different C's? how would I denote this?

Comment: Do you know separation of variables technique?

Comment: @science yea I learned it at one point (a very long time ago)

Comment: @Amzoti thanks! that was really helpful, I made a little more progress but am still struggling a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easier to do the definite integral. separate the variables like $\dfrac{dy}{y} = -\sqrt{1+t^2} \, dt.$ now integrating gives you 
$$\int_5^y\dfrac{dy}{y} = -\int_0^t \sqrt{1 + s^2}\, ds.$$ do the substitution $s = \tan u, ds = \dfrac{du}{\cos^2 u},b = \tan^{-1} t$  gets you
$$-\ln(y/5) = \int_0^b \dfrac{1}{\cos u} \dfrac{du}{\cos^2 u} = 
\int_0^b \sec^3 u\,du=\dfrac{1}{2}\left( t\sqrt{ 1+t^2} + \ln\left(\sqrt{1+t^2}+t \right) \right)$$

we used
$$2\int_0^b \sec^3 u \, du = \left(\sec u \tan u  + \ln (\sec u + \tan u)\right)_0^b = t\sqrt{ 1+t^2} + \ln\left(\sqrt{1+t^2}+t \right).$$

here is how prove the previous claim. 
$\begin{align}\int_0^b \sec^3 u \,du &= \int_0^b\sec u \,d \tan u \\
&= \sec u\tan u|_0^b - \int_0^b\tan u \sec u \tan u\, du \\
&=  \sec u\tan u|_0^b - \int_0^b(\sec^3 u - \sec u)\, du \\
&= \sec u\tan u + \ln (\sec u + \tan u)|_0^b - \int_0^b\sec^3 u \, du\end{align}$

Comment: How did you get the second part of the last line? I got $\int \sqrt {1+tan^2u} \frac{du}{cos^2u}=\int \sqrt {sec^2u} \frac{du}{cos^2u}=\int secu \frac{du}{cos^2u}$

Comment: Oh does it have something to do with the negative sign?

Comment: @MathMajor, thanks for spotting the error. it should be $\frac{1}{\cos u}$. i will fix it.

Comment: Also would you mind explaining the transition from the 3rd to the 4th step to me?

Comment: @MathMajor, hopefully all errors are fixed. check it out.

Comment: looks great! But do I need to solve explicitly for y? so take e to the power of your answer, multiply by 5

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider $t=\tan\theta$, then you would need the fact (derived from integration by parts): $\int \sec^3\theta \,d\theta= \tan\theta\sec\theta - \int\sec\theta\tan^2\theta\,d\theta$.

You should use $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$. Also with the technique I'm sharing with you you will end up with a cyclic integral (don't know if this is the name, but if the integral is $I$ then you will have an expression like $I=$ something $-I$, where you solve for $I$).